# How can I hide the separator at indexPath in tableView?It means ,remove specific separator，not all separators

Tags: ios, uitableview

if I don't hide the separator,the UI will be like as following:
[The normal status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmytz.png)

But What I need to do is going to hide a part of separator view in tableview.Such as:
[What i want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoWSY.png)

I had tried to set up the [separatorinset],but it didn't work.

Comment: You can change the separator style to None to hide it, it's in tableView attribute

Comment: I knew how hidd all separator,but the result what i expect is to hide the separator in cells at indexPath.just a part of separators ,not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this question for useing these codes:

`cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, FNDeviceWidth);//FNDeviceWidth,the cell's width
 cell.layoutMargins  = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
 cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO`

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of posting a comment.

Comment: gotcha.thanks your help